# How can I display an Error Message when my program can't connect to database?

Tags: c#, sql, log4net

I need to know a way to show a message or something like that when I compile my program and the user or password are wrong, because when I do this nothing happens.

I'm making a system that save logs.

log4net just using C#. if you can help me I'd appreciate.

thanks!

Comment: You want to display an error message when you **compile** the program? Or when you **run** the program? Anyway, you're giving so little information that it's almost impossible to give a useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do it at compile time, as far as I know.

Assuming you meant run time instead of compile time makes more sense. When you try to open the connection, use a try-catch block, and inside the catch block, log the error, display an alert, do whatever you need to do.

Is this what you need or can you give a more specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

If it is absolutely a requirement that the project not build if the connection string is invalid you can do something that is approximately like the following.

1. Store the username/password in some external/known location. i.e. config file.
2. Write a "DBConnect" app. All it does is load the connection, and have it exit with an error code if it cannot connect.
3. Include this "DBConnect.exe" in the pre-build of the particular project.

TaDa! The project will not build unless the connection string is valid.

Keep in mind, this only validates that the connection string is valid *from the build machine*. It does not validate that it can be accessed from anywhere else.